# How Does python-omgeo 1.7.0 Work

Tags: python, api, geocode

I am trying to use several geocoding APIs (Google,Bing, etc.) with Python to find the average Latitude/Longitude of an address. I just stumbled upon python-omgeo 1.7.0 and was trying to determine if that is already what python-omgeo does?

Does python-omgeo compare the results of its several different geocoding APIs to find the most likely/average result?

Thanks for clarifying this.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-omgeo